# How to setKeyEquivalent to Enter/Return key on NSButton?

Tags: cocoa, nsbutton

I've tried [myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\n"] but that didn't work. I feel like there should be some predefined constant for it that I'm just missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try using "\r" instead of "\n" in this case.

I believe [myButton setKeyEquivalent:@"\r"] should do what you are looking for.

Comment: Do not set this in your
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
function... That's what happened to me. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Example for Swift 2.0:

```swift
let key = String(utf16CodeUnits: [unichar(NSEnterCharacter)], count: 1) as String
item.keyEquivalent = key
item.keyEquivalentModifierMask = Int(NSEventModifierFlags.CommandKeyMask.rawValue | NSEventModifierFlags.ControlKeyMask.rawValue)
```

Comment: Shouldn't be `NSCarriageReturnCharacter` instead of `NSEnterCharacter` ?

Answer (score 0):

Beware that "as is", this will require to type Command + Return (which I think is Enter). To have this work without Command I had to add `[myButton setKeyEquivalentModifierMask:0];`.